# Help with the titlepage

Tags: titles

I need to write the title page for my work and I need that the author and director names be in the right side of the page, anyone can help me or give an idea?

This is what i tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,spanish,12pt,titlepage]{report}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \begin{center}
 \textsc{\LARGE Departament of My University}\\[0.4cm]
 \textsc{\large Name of University}\\[0.6cm]


 \textsc{\Large Final Work}\\[0.5cm]


 { \Huge \bfseries Name of my work}\\[0.4cm]



  \vspace{2\baselineskip}



  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
 \begin{flushright} \large
 \emph{Autor:} \\
  My Name\\
 \emph{Director:} \\
 My Director´s name
 \end{flushright}
 \end{minipage}


 {\large March, $2013$}
 \end{center}
 \end{titlepage}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Note that your code is not compilable as it is: you must load the `graphicx` package in order to use `\includegraphics`. Regarding your horizontal-alignment issue, I think you want to use a `flushright` rather than `flushleft`.

Comment: thanks for let me note that, actually the graphic doesn´t matter, so i erased from the example, and yes it was flushright, but it doen´t work as i want

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,spanish,12pt,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\LARGE Departament of My University}\\[0.4cm]
\textsc{\large Name of University}\\[0.6cm]
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./unc}~\\[1cm]
\textsc{\Large Final Work}\\[0.5cm]
{\Huge \bfseries Name of my work}

\vspace{5\baselineskip}

\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\large
\emph{Autor:} \\
My Name\\
\emph{Director:} \\
My Director´s name
\end{tabular}

\vfill

{\large March, 2013}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\hfill` to move to the right a `tabular` environment containing the names.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

I only used the `showframe` option for `geometry` to have a visual guideline; the lines in the image correspond to the margins enclosing the text area.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary answer: the output is not the one you intended, because the minipage is centered—only its content is flushed to the right.
It becomes clear if you add a box around it (thanks to the `boxedminipage` package):
[image: minipage boxed]

Adding an `\hfill` before the minipage solves the problem.